# Moving Code to Debian Caused "Use multi=True when executing multiple statements" Error Statements

Tags: python, python-3.x, mysql-python

I have been running python scripts making calls to MySQL on a machine with Ubuntu 20.04 LTS. I just recently moved those scripts over to a server running Debian 10.

Both servers have MySQL 8.0.21 installed. Python 3.7.3 is on the Debian server, and Python 3.8.2 on Ubuntu. When I execute the python scripts on the Debian server, I get the following error message:

`Use multi=True when executing multiple statements`

I haven't made any changes to the code, so I'm not sure why I'm getting this message on the Debian server, but not the Ubuntu one.

Here's the section in the script that causes the error:

```
cursor = dbconn.cursor(dictionary=True)

# get next scheduled event to be aired
sql = "CALL GetEvent();"
cursor.execute(sql)

result = cursor.fetchone()
cursor.close()

if result:  
    eventtime = str(result["eventtime"])

    # the max seconds we are going to wait is 60
    init_waitseconds = timediffinseconds(eventtime)
    if init_waitseconds > 61:
        waitseconds = 60
    else:
        waitseconds = init_waitseconds

    # wait for specified time
    print_stdout(f"{bcolors.CGREEN}[EVENT_MONITOR]{bcolors.ENDC} Waiting for next scheduled event at {eventtime}")
    time.sleep(waitseconds)
```

The stored procedure that is called is as follows:

```
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `GetEvent`()
BEGIN
    
    DECLARE v_DayName CHAR(9);    
    SET v_DayName := DAYNAME(CURRENT_DATE);
    
    SELECT e.name, e.eventaction, e.data, e.extra, et.eventday, et.eventtime, et.recurring
        FROM event e
        INNER JOIN eventtime et ON et.eventID = e.ID
        WHERE et.eventdate = CURDATE() AND et.recurring = 'No' AND e.enabled = 1 AND et.eventtime > CURRENT_TIME() OR           
            et.eventday = 'v_DayName' AND et.recurring = 'Yes' AND e.enabled = 1 AND et.eventtime > CURRENT_TIME() OR
            et.eventday = 'Day' AND et.recurring = 'Yes' AND e.enabled = 1 AND et.eventtime > CURRENT_TIME() OR
            CASE WHEN IsWeekday('v_DayName') = True THEN et.eventday = 'Mon-Fri' END AND e.enabled = 1 AND et.eventtime > CURRENT_TIME() OR
            CASE WHEN IsWeekend('v_DayName') = True THEN et.eventday = 'Sat-Sun' END AND e.enabled = 1 AND et.eventtime > CURRENT_TIME()
        ORDER BY et.eventtime
        LIMIT 1;
END
```

Also, this section of my python script causes the same error:

```
cursor = dbconn.cursor(dictionary=True)

# CheckQueueCount MySQL procedure retrieves how many tracks are currently in queuelist table
sql = "CALL CheckQueueCount"
cursor.execute(sql)

result = cursor.fetchone()
ret = result["QueueCount"]
cursor.close()
return ret
```

And the stored procedure it calls:

```
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `CheckQueueCount`()
BEGIN

    SELECT COUNT(ID) AS QueueCount FROM queuelist;
    
END
```

Comment: Which (Python) package are you using to connect to the database?  Is the version the same on both machines?

Comment: I assume you are referring to the mysql-connector. How do I check those to see which versions are installed?

Comment: `pip list | grep -i 'mysql-connector'`, taking care to use the right version of `pip`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I believe I solved the issue. I uninstalled the connector that had been installed with the command:

```
sudo pip3 install mysql-connector
```

and instead, installed it with:

```
sudo pip3 install mysql-connector-python
```

Errors have gone away.